# GWT timezone issue

Tags: java, gwt

From few days I am fighting with different Timezone issues of server and GWT client. but cannot get any success.

Scenario is Server is in UTC timezone let say Client A is in IST timezone.
When client select a date (with time) I pushed to server but date is automatically changed to server's timezone. I dig around this issue and I found multiple solutions like

1. create custom serializer (No idea how to do that can't found any proper example)
2. transfer date as a string to server and convert it to server timezone and store it. and when fetching data convert again from server's timezone to client local timezone. sounds good idea.

So my query is.

1. Any other solutions?
2. which is best way to manage this ?
3. any sample code or link?

Comment: Read my post here [Why Date is not Serializing in GWT 2.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824835/why-date-is-not-serializing-in-gwt-2-6?answertab=votes#tab-top). It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply format the date in UTC format at client side and pass the date as string to the server and store the data in UTC format in database as well.

On the server side everything would be fine, since formatting the date would use the timezone of the server, which is what the date is stored in. On the client side, however, GWT will use the timezone of the client machine, and so there could be a discrepancy.

Sample code:

```
DateTimeFormat f = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
TimeZoneConstants t = (TimeZoneConstants) GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class)
TimeZone est = TimeZone.createTimeZone(t.americaNewYork());
int offset = est.isDaylightTime(date) ? +240 : +300;
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.createTimeZone(offset);
String date = f.format(user.getBirthDate(), est);
```

---

There are a few other possible solutions, but one of these two might do the trick.

- [How do I get GWT DateTimeFormat to display using the server TimeZone, rather than the client's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189148/how-do-i-get-gwt-datetimeformat-to-display-using-the-server-timezone-rather-tha)

Comment: So should I follow solution 2? I mean is it better idea to store all dates in after converting UTC format?

Comment: Yes store the dates in UTC format in database to make it consistent.

Comment: How to get client's timezone on server side for conversion? Let my app locale is en_US but my timezone is IST. when I try to convert date with this code it convert date in UTC format and it is not correct.

Comment: Simply convert it into UTC format at client side and then pass the formatted value to the server.

Comment: I think there is no need to create manually timezone conversation. I found a bug in my code.  I was storing dateTime as 

preparedStatement.setDate(index++,
        new Date(dto.getSchedule().getTime()));

but what I changed is  just

preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index++, new Timestamp(dto.getSchedule().getTime()));

so it store time also. If I am not wrong GWT transfer Date in timestamp so no need to convert manually date. If I am missing somthing please suggest.

And Thanks for your help

Comment: The only remaining problem might be if you are doing date calculations on the client. In that case it will be done in the timezone of the client. We happily use RequestFactory, JODA time and data types (with and without timezone). The only horrible thing we had to do is have our own implementation of java.util.Date (on the client) to do all calculations in UTC.

Comment: I have mentioned a sample code to format the date in NewYork America timezone. Do in the same way for UTC.